# Ring Identities

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, summation, quaternions

Suppose we had a finite group G with elements $e_0, e_1 ... e_k$

Then consider objects from the set

$$ M = { a_0 e_0 + a_1 e_1 + a_2 e_2 ... a_n e_k }, a_i \in \Bbb{R}$$

whereas

$$ m + n, (m,n \in M) $$

Is just summation component wise for each element in the group. And

$$ m*n = m_0 n_0 e_0^2 + m_0 n_1 e_0 e_1 + m_0 n_2 e_0 e_2 ... $$

And each expression $e_i e_j$ is simplified using the underlying group structure.

A concrete example being the famous Quaternions:

How does one simplify infinite sums over such structures.

An example is over $\Bbb{C}$ it is challenging to resolve:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^2}} = \frac{\pi^2 }{6} $$

But what if we consider the following over $\Bbb{H}$ (the Quaternions)

$$ \sum_{d=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(d-j)(d+k)}} $$

It's not clear how to do this, as most of the conventional tools such as the trigonometric functions etc... don't seem to be well defined. Yet I could algorithmically find sequences of elements in the Quaternions that converge to whatever that sum comes down to.

Comment: $M$ endowed with $+$ and $\ast$ is called the *group ring* $\Bbb R G$. But note that for $G = Q_8$ the group ring is not the same as the quaternions: $\Bbb R Q_8$ is an $8$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb R$ but $\Bbb H$ is a $4$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: In short, this happens because, e.g., $1 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot (-1) \in \Bbb R Q_8$ is nonzero but regarded as an object in $\Bbb H$ it is zero. We can formalize this observation (and remedy the situation) by reducing $\Bbb R Q_8$ modulo the vector space $\langle 1 + (-1), i + (-i), j + (-j), k + (-k) \rangle$ and check directly that $\ast$ descends to a well-defined product on this quotient space, namely, to the usual quaternionic multiplication.

Comment: Anyway, if you're in particular interested in expressions like the above sum of reciprocals I think it's better to disregard the role of group rings in the quaternion example. Expressions like $\frac{1}{(d-j)(d+k)}$ only make sense because $\Bbb H$ is a division ring, i.e., because we can take inverses of arbitrary nonzero elements, and we cannot do this in a typical group ring.

Comment: @Travis, what about rings where each element e, either has a unique inverse, or is not invertible? in that case we can consider sums that don't involve division by non-invertible elements.

Comment: Ah ignore that, I understand the problem. It's not clear at all how to yield the multiplicative identity by division for most elements in one of my constructions.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas *what about rings where each element either has a unique inverse, or is not invertible?* All rings satisfy that.